# Question on strictly increasing, differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis

3. (a) Let $a, b ∈ R, a < b $ and $f : [a, b] → R.$ State what it means to say that $f$ is differentiable on $[a, b]$. Assume that $f$ is differentiable on $[a, b].$

(i) Show that $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$.

(ii) Suppose that $f$ is strictly increasing. Let $m = f(a) $ and $M = f(b)$. Show
that there exists a continuous function $g : [m,M] → [a, b]$ such that
$g(f(x)) = x$ and $f(g(y)) = y$ for every $x ∈ [a, b]$ and $y ∈ [m,M]$.

(iii) Show further that if $x_0 ∈ (a, b)$ and $f′(x0) \not= 0$, then $g$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $g′(x0) = 1/f′(x0)$.

The first part gave me no trouble. In the second part I proved that the inverse exists and satisfies the conditions of $g$ and then that $g$ is continuous.

I am having trouble proving the third part.

Comment: About derivatives, what have you learned so far?

Comment: The third part is contained in what is called the inverse function theorem. You probably had it in your lecture.

Comment: @xbh The definition of derivative, chain rule, derivatives of sums, products of functions etc. We have not covered Metric Spaces or anything like that.

Comment: I would actually say that $g'(f(x_0))= \frac{1}{f'(x_0)}$. Right?

Comment: @Libabol Then I think (iii) is doable. Definition would work. As a way to understand why $g'(f(x_0)) = 1/f'(x_0)$, try the **chain rule**.

Comment: Statement iii) should in fact be re-stated like this. *Show further that if $x_0\in [a,b]$ and $f'(x_0)\neq 0$ then $g$ is differentiable in $f(x_0)$ and $g'(f(x_0)) = \frac{1}{f'(x_0)}$*. Then, as pointed out by @xbh, you can use chain rule plus definition $g(f(x)) = x$, for example. How about that?